# RSA cryptosystem find p and q of large n when private key is not given

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I was working on a RSA problem to decrypt some given strings.

The public key is given as (n, e) where:

n = 679372223375244767426661823611571709377236531593801193332198472747214909

e = 389263491409977986099492708162379040578860053202851003849443831378701

The private key d is not given, How do I find p and q for the corresponding n?
Any method I use to factorize n proves to be inefficient.

Comment: The point of RSA is that factoring is difficult. If there is/were a shortcut, RSA is/would be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Ask [Alpertron](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) to perform the factorization:

```
n = 780535 675704 985143 085937 429075 336653 (36 digits)
  × 870392 276127 072787 672802 596403 119153 (36 digits)
```

Comment: Good tool, but you seem to have copied the wrong answer out of it (your value is the one for a^2 + b^2).  `780535 675704 985143 085937 429075 336653 (36 digits) × 870392 276127 072787 672802 596403 119153 (36 digits)` is the correct answer, as it produces the correct value for `n` after plugging it back in.

Comment: Fixed. The dyslexia is strong dotay.